# AF-S NIKKOR 50mm f/1.4G or AF NIKKOR 50mm f/1.4D?

Tags: lens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [nikon lens- to G or not to G?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6179/nikon-lens-to-g-or-not-to-g)

AF-S NIKKOR 50mm f/1.4G for $484
AF NIKKOR 50mm f/1.4D for $369

is the G worth 100$ more?

also, i imagine that the G is somehow better to warrant the additional cost. can anyone explain how?

(this will be my 2nd lens to my nikon d7000 kit lens.)

Comment: This is a virtual duplicate of your question from last night. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6179/

Comment: Good point, I've moved my answer to that question.

Comment: Kacalapy, try to keep your questions distinct, so we don't clutter the forum with numerous highly similar questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The G actually makes it cheaper, the AF-S makes it more expensive.

Comment: can i get a nikon lens with G but not AF-S?

Comment: Not in a prime ~ the only one they make that is both AF (not AF-S) and G is the 27-300mm f/4
http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/1928/AF-Zoom-NIKKOR-70-300mm-f%252F4-5.6G.html
Here is a link to ALL Nikkor lenses:
http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Camera-Lenses/index.page