# Which lens to d7000? 50mm 1.4g or 1.4d?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, nikon-d7000

I need to buy a lens to make portraits with my Nikon d7000.

I know that for every camera model lenses behave differently, so how do these lenses perform with the d7000?

Can I save money and buy the 1.4d instead of the 1.4g?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nikon lenses: to G or not to G?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6179/nikon-lenses-to-g-or-not-to-g)

Comment: Actually the 50mm 1.4D only works with f16 on my D7000 - all of the rest of the fstops display a fEE error. I also have problems with the auto focus function.

Comment: Are you sure that you need that f1.4 and can't use the 50 f/1.8?

Answer (score 1):

Considering all G are D, buy the cheapest one you find considering :

- D can be used on a more bodies than G, as they feature an aperture ring (this is not relevant if you only plan to use modern bodies with dials to set aperture)
- G are probably more convenient if you use speed priority
- personal choice matters : personally I prefer G as I like to do everything with the dials

Comment: Neither the D nor the G can be used to their fullest on all Nikon bodies -- the D can be used on older bodies that lack compatibility with G lenses, but the G includes a built-in autofocus motor (AF-S) that makes it useable on lower-end Nikon digital bodies, like the D3100 or D5100 -- the D lens would be manual focus-only on these bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both lenses can be used with the D7000 in a normal portrait situation.

According to Nikon the D means that the lens sends distance information to the camera body. This can then be used to track moving objects and adjust the focus accordingly. For a normal portrait situation this would not be a vital functionality.  This is useful for moving objects, like children running around.

G means that the lens does not a have a manual ring for the aperture. With the D7000 you do not need a aperture ring on the lens as you can select the aperture using the camera body.

Comment: so In your opinion better buy 1.4 d, yes?

Comment: The G lenses also send distance information, the only difference is the missing aperture ring - http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3399/~/what-is-a-nikon-af-g-lens

Comment: I would buy the cheaper one. Yes, that was unclear. G does also send the same distance information as D does.

Comment: The distance information does not help **at all** in tracking moving subjects, nor does it help in adjusting the focus. The lens cannot tell the body about where the subject is. It works the other way around: the AF system in the body adjusts the focus, and _then_ the lens can tell the body what distance it has been set to.

Answer (score 0):

Either lens will work just fine on the D7000. The differences come into play with old film cameras (F4 and older, IIRC) which need an aperture ring (you can't use G lenses fully) and entry-level DSLRs that don't have a built-in focus motor.

The G is an AF-S lens, while the non-G lens is not. An AF-S lens has a built-in focus motor, which means that it can auto-focus with cameras that do not have an in-body focus motor. Since the D7000 has an in-body focus motor, it can auto-focus with either lens.

The other advantage of AF-S lenses is that you can override auto-focus and tweak where the camera is focusing by simply grabbing the focus ring and turning it. The camera senses that you turned the ring and stops trying to focus automatically. With the non-G lens, you'll have to actually flip a switch to turn off auto-focus.

The G lens does not have an aperture ring, but that doesn't really make a difference on the D7000 as you can still use every function exactly the same with the non-G lens. You can lock the aperture ring on f/16 and let the camera control it.